# Not able to display same output for Linked List twice in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a linked list and came up with `add` function which helps add new elements to the list and `display` function to display the list. When I call the `display` function it shows me the result but when I call the `display` function again it won't show me the results

I clearly have no idea what else to do

```
    class Node:
      def __init__(self,data=None):
        self.data=data
        self.pointer=None

    class Llist:
      def __init__(self):
        self.rootpointer=None

      def addlist(self,newdata):
        self.newdata=newdata
        node4=Node(newdata)
        node4.pointer=self.rootpointer
        self.rootpointer=node4

      def Dispaylist(self):
        while self.rootpointer is not None :
          print (self.rootpointer.data)
          self.rootpointer=self.rootpointer.pointer

linkedlist=Llist()
linkedlist.rootpointer=Node('A')
linkedlist.rootpointer.pointer=Node('B')
linkedlist.rootpointer.pointer.pointer=Node('C')

linkedlist.addlist('D')
linkedlist.Dispaylist()
linkedlist.Dispaylist()
```

It displays correct output as `D A B C` but when I call the `Display` function again it won't show me anything. Can we not call same function again in order to get the output, I do not think that's the case because I remember calling the same function twice before and was able to get the output. So I think I am missing something here, Could someone give me some pointers please?

Comment: In the `Displaylist` method you are modifying `self.rootpointer`. This means the next time you call the method, the value of the root pointer will be `None`. You should use a copy of `self.rootpointer` instead.

Comment: Every time you traverse along the nodes, you change the rootpointer to the pointer of the next node. So when you display the list the first time around, your pointer is at the end of the list so next time around, there is nothing more to show. As @Deepstop suggested, you can use a copy and display that or have a way to put the rootpointer back to the first node after finish displaying.

Comment: @Deepstop I did not understand your comment at first glance , you could be more specific that could help noobs like me .

Comment: @RisingSun Your explanation is perfect , I have tried it and It worked , Thanks so much for the help

Comment: Well I figured if you were implementing a linked list as a class you wouldn't be too much of a noob. Anyway I'm glad you have your answer.